# Bootstrap 4 Rounded circle image can't get it to be responsive

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have in image centered on the page through a container which I'm not really sure is the correct way to do it but it worked until I found out the problem I have which is it doesn't get resized!! i tried the img-fluid as bootstrap documentation says but i think the issue might be with the container?

```
.center-logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -15%);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/style1.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
   <div class = "center-logo">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/img%20(30).jpg" class="rounded-circle" alt="...">
  </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add this `width: 100%;height: auto;` to your img not to the container

Comment: now should i do that with a style tag ? img { width: 100%;height: auto;} or should i do it the css file?? im not that experienced . does it make any difference where i put it?
ok so yes it does scale but the image now is huge

Comment: the img is huge because it takes the width of the container. you can set max-width: for the image. If you are not experienced i'll suggest to read some online tutorials.

Comment: i have been reading tutorials and trying to find out how to do it but to no avail, thats why i thought human interaction could help me a bit better! thank you for the help! i'll try some more!

Answer (score 0):

The image is small and it is resizing correctly but the max width and height is 250px; you should use a bigger image to resize correctly in larger screens.

Comment: i see , well i tried it with a different picture but first the image-circle class makes it look like an egg instead of a circle and i dont really know how to set the size to be smaller. as it is i have set the style of the image to be max-width:100% and height: auto

Comment: is it the new image a square too?

Comment: yes it is a square as original but it turns into an egg with the rounded circle class. the funny part is that if i tinker with this https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/ascensus/127174#html-tab-view and add the img-fluid class it works. but i downloaded it on my pc and tried it but it doesnt work there. even if i remove all containers and everything on the site im trying to build and i leave just the css and the image tag it still wont ger resized

Comment: it should work with the img-fluid class if the image is placed within a container or container-fluid element